# How to create a small program in DXL (doors extensive language)?

Tags: ibm-doors

I just started learning doors DXL language. I need to create a small program in which:

> Open a module and print all objects along with objects and print 1 or 2 attribute values. If there is no attribute send error saying attribute does not exists

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You should acquire the DXL manual, e.g. from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf and check the examples. Look up how to

- read modules (*Module read*),
- iterate over all objects of a module (*for object in module*),
- access attributes (*Attribute value extraction*).

Your question is unclear: should there be a warning if the attribute does not exist or if the object's attribute contains no data? Look up either of those functions: `bool exists(attribute(string attributeName))` or `null`

This would give you something like that:

```
Module mod = read ("my/module")
if (!exists(attribute "attr1") || !exists(attribute "attr2"))
   errorBox ("attr1 or attr2 do not exist")
else {
   Object obj
   for obj in mod do {
     print obj."Object Text" "\n"
     if (!null obj."attr1") print "\t" obj."attr1" "\n"
     if (!null obj."attr1") print "\t" obj."attr1" "\n"
   }
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will start looking in to the dxl link that you provided me. My question is to send error if attribute does not exists and print 1 or 2 attribute values if they exists.

Comment: @rama: If the answer solves your problem, you may accept it as solution (green check mark). Once you have a reputation of 15: if you like an answer, you may upvote it.